# Connecting to Azure DevOps (TFS) Server with VssConnection and username/password

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Hello trying to connect with my username/password that I use in VS or when logging on web site - but I get this error: VssUnauthorizedException: 'VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://dev.azure.com.'

Or do I have to use a rest oauth token?

```
        var serverUrl = new Uri("https://dev.azure.com/mysite/");
        var clientCredentials = new VssBasicCredential(username, password);
        var connection = new VssConnection(serverUrl, clientCredentials);

        var buildServer = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();
        var sourceControlServer = connection.GetClient<TfvcHttpClient>();

        var changesets = buildServer.GetChangesBetweenBuildsAsync("My Project", 1, 1000).Result;
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following code:

```
var u = new Uri("https://dev.azure.com/mysite");
VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential(new NetworkCredential("username", "password")));
var connection = new VssConnection(u, c);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see you are trying to connect to the azure devops service because your url is https://dev.azure.com/mysite. For TFS we use this template: http://server_name:8080/tfs.

You can not use a user name and password for azure devops service. Use a [personal access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops) and this code:

```
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri("your_url"), new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, "your_pat"));
```

Additional information: [Authenticating (Azure DevOps Services)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples?view=azure-devops#authenticating-azure-devops-services)